# Searching a text file in java and Listing the results

Tags: java, search, io

I've really searched around for ideas on how to go about this, and so far nothing's turned up.

I need to search a text file via keywords entered in a JTextField and present the search results to a user in an array of columns, like how google does it. The text file has a lot of content, about 22,000 lines of text. I want to be able to sift through lines not containing the words specified in the JTextField and only present lines containing at least one of the words in the JTextField in rows of search results, each row being a line from the text file.

Anyone has any ideas on how to go about this? Would really appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line and search in every line for your keywords. If you find one, store the line in an array.

But first split you text box String by whitespaces and create the array:

```
String[]          keyWords = yourTextBoxString.split(" ");
ArrayList<String> results  = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Reading the file line by line:

```
void readFileLineByLine(File file) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String         line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       processOneLine(line);
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Processing the line:

```
void processOneLine(String line) {
    for (String currentKey : keyWords) {
        if (line.contains(currentKey) {
            results.add(line);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have not testst this, but you should get a overview on how you can do this.

If you need more speed, you can also use a [RegularExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to search for the keywords so you don't need this for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Read in file, as per the Oracle tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#textfiles Iterate through each line and search for your keyword(s) using String's contain method. If it contains the search phrase, place the line and line number in a results List. When you've finished you can display the results list to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method as follows:

```
List<String> searchFile(String path, String match){

        List<String> linesToPresent = new ArrayList<String>();

        File f = new File(path);
        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
                do{
                    line = br.readLine();
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(match);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                    if(m.find())
                        linesToPresent.add(line);
                } while(line != null);

                br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return linesToPresent;
    }
```

It searches a file line by line and checks with regex if a line contains a "match" String. If you have many Strings to check you can change the second parameter to `String[] match` and with a foreach loop check for each String match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : 
[FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

This will read each line and return you a `List<String>`.

You can iterate over this `List<String>` and check whether the `String` contains the word entered by the user, if it contains, add it to another `List<String>`. then at the end you will be having another `List<String>` which contains all the lines which contains the word entered by the user. You can iterate this `List<String>` and display the result to the user.